# Is jzmq deprecated?

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq, jeromq

Looking the ZeroMQ bindings. I found that [jzmq last release was almost three years ago](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/442). Is this binding deprecated?

On the other hand there is a native java implementation of ZeroMQ called JeroMQ which is supported by the ZeroMQ community and has a lot of activity in [Github](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) and it is based on one of the latest versions of libzmq(4.1.7).

Should all new Java development using ZeroMQ be based on JeroMQ? ([Considering that jzmq and JeroMQ APIs are starting to diverge](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/496))

How JeroMQ interoperate with ZeroMQ bindings in other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How JeroMQ interoperate with ZeroMQ bindings in other languages?

JeroMQ's API has diverged from that of jzmq, but this should have no impact on what's happening at the protocol level. You can write a Java program using JeroMQ and have it communicate with other programs written in other languages / runtimes.

> Should all new Java development using ZeroMQ be based on JeroMQ?

jzmq is still potentially useful if performance is very critical to your application, and if requiring end users to install libzmq is acceptable for you.

I looked at the GitHub repo for jzmq, and was surprised to find that, as you said, the last release was 3 years ago in 2014. This is especially surprising given that there have been commits on master as recently as March 2017. So, it looks like the project is still being maintained, but they are rather overdue for a release.